# Remove all css from a html element using JQuery or CSS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table and I want to make cell editable by showing the input element when user click the cell and I want to give the same height and width to input that cell have. The problem is I am using Angular Material and they have some style on input element (not through class) and it overrides the class or inline style which I am trying to apply on input element. So how can I remove those style from input element with jQuery?

Css is apply like this

```
input {
-webkit-appearance: textfield;
background-color: white;
-webkit-rtl-ordering: logical;
user-select: text;
cursor: auto;
padding: 1px;
border-width: 2px;
border-style: inset;
border-color: initial;
border-image: initial;
}
```

Comment: `.removeAttr('style')`

Comment: show what you are doing..

Comment: currently I have not idea  because to remove class removeClass can be used and to remove inline css .removeAttr('style') can be used but for this I don't know

Comment: If you don't want those styles, why can't you just override those styles with your own by using a more specific selector?  Also, why do you need to use jquery to remove the style instead of just doing it with css?  Show your class that is overriden

Comment: i suggest just override the previous with what ever style you want. by adding a class or id with style. ID will be the most ideal selector to use then put what ever style you want

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it with jQuery like below

```js
$("input").focus(function(){ $(this).css("all","unset"); });
```

```css
input {
-webkit-appearance: textfield;
background-color: white;
-webkit-rtl-ordering: logical;
user-select: text;
cursor: auto;
padding: 1px;
border-width: 2px;
border-style: inset;
border-color: red;
border-image: initial;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text"  />
```

You can do it with css like below

```css
input {
-webkit-appearance: textfield;
background-color: white;
-webkit-rtl-ordering: logical;
user-select: text;
cursor: auto;
padding: 1px;
border-width: 2px;
border-style: inset;
border-color: red;
border-image: initial;
}

input:focus {
  all: initial;
  * {
    all: unset;
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text"  />
```

Comment: border is gone.

Comment: Welcome.  you can use this if you want to do it in jquery. $("input").focus(function(){
$(this).css("all","unset");

});

Comment: October 2018: [IE doesn't support the property "all"](https://caniuse.com/#search=all)

Comment: Not the best solution. When you then set any CSS attribute - at least in Chrome - all other attributes are set explicitly as unset. `$("input").removeAttr('style');` is the better solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  //$("#inp1").removeAttr('style');
  $("input").removeAttr('style');
  //$("input [type='text']").removeAttr('style');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" style="height:40px;" id="inp1"/>
```

Answer (score -1):

$("class/tag/id").removeAttr('style/class/id');

Comment: it is not applied through class but through element like this input{}

Comment: You can use any selector . I just given an example

Answer (score -1):

For inline css use `removeAttr('style')` but for the styles getting applied via css, you need to remove classes as well. use `removeAttr('class')` for this.

if the css is applied on tag, thenbest way is to add a class like active and add the css you want to it like `.active { border-style: none, ... }` etc.

Comment: but css is not apply through class it is applied like this
input {
    -webkit-appearance: textfield;
    background-color: white;
    -webkit-rtl-ordering: logical;
    user-select: text;
    cursor: auto;
    padding: 1px;
    border-width: 2px;
    border-style: inset;
    border-color: initial;
    border-image: initial;
}

Comment: then you need to remove the styles one by one but the best way is to add a class like **active** and add the css you want to it like
.active { border-style: none, ... } etc.

Comment: if you find the answer useful, then please upvote it.